# How to detect when scroll bottom height is < 30

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working script which detects when user scrolled completely to bottom. However, I want to detect when scroll bottom height is < 30px.

```
var elem = $("#content");
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
$('#olderposts').load('olderposts.php');
}
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just deduct it:

```
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() <= elem.outerHeight() - 30) {
```

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it not worked. Are you sure its correct ?

Comment: This is for full page *** if($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight > $(document).height() - 30) { *** How to make it work on this one ?

Comment: You are using `>` sign. Perhaps `==` will help you ?

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found that this is the correct method

```
if (elem.scrollTop() >= elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.outerHeight() - 30) {
```